# How to define an array with no initial value of size in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a program that gets user's input to an array of the type string, but as I don't know how many items the user gonna put in, I have to create the array empty as I know, so when I try to create the array with no initial value that error comes in.

ERROR:  [Error's Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLYE.png)

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > * listOfItems" (?listOfItems@@3PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)
```

Here is the image of the code [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2sUC.png).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string listOfItems[];

void getInfoToArray()
{
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        //Get the info of the array.
        std::cin >> listOfItems[i];

        //Check if the user input is -1.
        if (listOfItems[i] == "-1") break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    getInfoToArray();
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone has a better solution than trying to create an empty array, I'd be thankful.

Comment: Use std::vector<std::string> instead.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Comment: Thanks Vlad, and how can I reputate you for answering?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, try using std::vector instead.

However, if you do want to use arrays, you have to define the size of the array in advance.

You may use  the new command and set the size of the array dynamically, at run time.

```
   // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string *listOfItems;

void getInfoToArray(int n)
{
    listOfItems = new std::string[n];
    for (int i = 0;i<n; i++)
    {
        //Get the info of the array.
        std::cin >> listOfItems[i];

        //Check if the user input is -1.
        if (listOfItems[i] == "-1") break;
    }
}

int main()
{

//    getInfoToArray();
    int size;
    std::cout<<"enter size of array"
    std::cin >> size;
        getInfoToArray(size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        std::cout<<listOfItems[i]<<"  ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the other way to do it without getting that input from the user is to set a predefined max size. This is static allocation, compile time. Something like,

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string listOfItems[10];

void getInfoToArray()
{
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        //Get the info of the array.
        std::cin >> listOfItems[i];

        //Check if the user input is -1.
        if (listOfItems[i] == "-1" && i<9) break;
    }
}

int main()
{
        getInfoToArray();
    return 0;
}
```

This is all because memory is alloted in the start for an array, unless you use a pointer.

Please feel free to comment if you have any doubts